# Laser line detection using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a project in which I need to detect a red laser line in an image. This is the strategy I have in mind.

1. Separate the R, G, B channels in the image.
2. Threshold the images at a high intensity value.
3. Using the 3 binary images generated, perform the element wise operation r && !g && !b. (&& is logical AND, ! is logical NOT).
4. The resulting matrix is a binary image with 1 on the regions where the laser was present.

This worked with a few test images on Matlab. But my problem is that this needs to be implemented using OpenCV in C/ C++.

I've tried going through most of the library functions, but there seems no intuitive/ simple way of working with binary images and performing logical operations on them.

Can someone please point me to the OpenCV functions/ methods that you think I might find useful? I've figured that `cvThresholdImage` can be used for thresholding, but that's pretty much about it.

Comment: This might be better suited for the [DSP Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/faq). Perhaps have it migrated there if you think it might be a better fit. Check first though. I don't participate there, so I might be wrong. (Don't cross-post please).

Comment: Can you show an example of an image? Also really consider migrating this question to DSP, you question is just about digital signal processing.

Comment: I can see how this question is applicable here.  As I understand it he is not asking for techniques to detect the laser, he has already developed his technique.  What he is asking for is information on using openCV to implement that technique.

Comment: @Hammer: Ah, this way I should upvote for your answer :)

Comment: @ffriend I guess I do have a bit of a conflict of interest :)

Comment: What about using cv::bitwise_and, cv::bitwise_not...

Comment: @QuentinGeissmann that is a much simpler idea than my answer, i didn't know those functions existed.  I would be interested to know the speed tradeoffs of calling those 3 times vs 1 loop with 3 operations

Answer (score 3):

So you already figured out steps 1 and 2 in openCV then?  If you are just trying to use the logical operators, openCV gives you access to the raw data which you can then operate on with logical operators.  Assuming you have already split into three channels and thresholded

```
//three binary images in the format you specified above
cv::Mat g;
cv::Mat b;
cv::Mat r;
uchar* gptr = g.data();
uchar* bptr = b.data();
uchar* rptr = r.data();

//assuming the matrix data is continuous you can just iterate straight through the data
if(g.isContinuous()&&r.isContinuous()&&b.isContinuous())
{  
  for(int i = 0; i < g.rows*g.cols; i++)
  {
     rptr[i] = rptr[i]&&!bptr[i]&&!gptr[i];
  }
}
```

r now contains the output you described.  You could also copy it into a new matrix if you don't want to overwrite r.

There are several ways of iterating through a cv::Mat and accessing all the data points and C++ provides all the logical operators you could want.  To my knowledge openCV does not provide matrix logical operator functions but you could write your own very easily as shown above.

**Edit**
As suggested by QuentinGeissmann you could accomplish the same thing using the bitwise_not and bitwise_and functions.  I was not aware that they existed.  I suspect that using them would be slower because of the number of times the data must be iterated through but it could be done in less code.

```
cv::bitwise_not(g,g);
cv::bitwise_not(b,b);
cv::bitwise_and(b,g,b);
cv::bitwise_and(r,b,r);
//r now contains r&&!b&&!g
```

Comment: Hammer, thanks for the response. Yes - this is pretty much what I was looking for. Will work on this and get back to you. You suggest working with cv::Mat and not IplImage ?

Comment: @tetradeca7tope It is really just a matter of preference.  cv::Mat is the new c++ interface the other is from the C interface.  I only have experience with the C++ so I can't really advise you about the differences.  I have heard that you should avoid mixing them though so if you are already committed to Iplimage perhaps you should stick with that.  You can just access its .imageData instead of .data for cv::Mat

Comment: Intuitively, it should be slower to use cv::bitwise_not/and... let us know which is the fastest "for you" if you end-up trying both :)

Comment: Turns out the cv::bitwise operations are faster. I am dealing with VGA images so I am not sure how they scale up. Thanks a lot everybody !

Comment: @tetradeca7tope you're welcome.  A great way to say thank you on SO is to accept/upvote answers.